# How to copy input from entry field and copy to clipboard with Tkninter and Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Try to copy to clipboard with Tkninter from the entry input field.
For example, write in the entry, set to str, press button to copy to clipboard.
Every time I push the button I get None printed to console and the window closes.

```
from tkinter import * 


root = Tk()

e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
newText = e.get() 

class Main(object):
   
 
def ThisWorks():
    print(e.get())

def callback(text=newText): 
    root.withdraw()       
    root.clipboard_clear
    root.clipboard_append(newText)
    print(root.clipboard_append(newText))

b = Button(root, text="test", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack()
b2 = Button(root, text="test2", width=10, command=ThisWorks)
b2.pack()


butquit = Button(root, text="exit", command=root.quit)
butquit.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven_programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). Read through [`[tkinter] event driven programming`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Btkinter%5D+event+driven+programming+entry)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `e.get()` inside `callback`. `newText` only has the value at the time you called `e.get()`, and you called it about a millisecond after creating the entry widget. The user won't even have seen the widget, much less had a chance to enter any data.